# C# Screen.DeviceName

Tags: windows

This is a very simple question about Screen.DeviceName

Does it always return "\.\DISPLAY1" to "\.\DISPLAY"n ? or are there any values except from those?

I have multiple monitors and I have like "\.\DISPLAY1" "\.\DISPLAY2" "\.\DISPLAY3"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the covers this just calls the [`GetMonitorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144901%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Windows API function. There is no mention of a specific format that the name will always be in in the documentation.

The device name itself being returned is therefore an implementation detail of the OS and potentially liable to change between releases, or in a software update. I'd strongly recommend you don't assume it will always be in that format, even if - for now - it is.

Comment: aha! Great info. Thanks for that!

Comment: How to get name of display  like in settings Windows (1, 2, 3)? I got 1= "\.\DISPLAY1, 2= "\.\DISPLAY3", 3 = "\.\DISPLAY2"